# Need VBScript to list disabled accounts

Tags: vbscript

The following script check local computers for inactive (90 days or more) accounts and disables them.  The script works fine, but it lists all the disabled accounts every time is executed.  I only need it to list the accounts that have been disabled the day is was executed.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objNetwork, strComputer, objComputer, objUser, dtmLast, objGroup, ObjGroupDict
Dim FSO, OutPutFile

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'1 = reading, 2 = writing, and 8 = appending. The third parameter is a
'boolean true means a new file can be created if it doesn't exist. False
'means a new file cannot be created.
Set OutPutFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Test\Result.log", 8, True)

'Bind to the local computer.
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName
Set objComputer = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & ",computer")

'Enumerate all users.
objComputer.Filter = Array("user")
For Each objUser In objComputer
    Set ObjGroupDict = CreateMemberOfObject(objUser)

    If ((Left(objUser.Name,3) <> "au_") And (CBool(ObjGroupDict.Exists("Administrators") = False))) Then
        'Trap error if user never logged in.
        On  Error Resume Next
        dtmLast = objUser.lastLogin
        If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
            dtmLast = #1/1/1970#
        End If

        On  Error GoTo 0

        'Check if last logon was more than 90 days in the past.
        If (DateDiff("d", dtmLast, Now()) > 90) Then
            'Disable the user.
            objUser.AccountDisabled = True
            objUser.SetInfo

            OutPutFile.WriteLine(Now & " " & strComputer & " " & Wscript.ScriptName & " " & objUser.Name & " " & "Disabled")
            'MsgBox objUser.Name

            Set FSO = Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next

Function CreateMemberOfObject(objUser)
    'Given a domain name and username, returns a Dictionary
    'object of groups to which the user is a member of.
    'Inputs: objUser - User Object

    Set CreateMemberOfObject = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    CreateMemberOfObject.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim objGroup
    For Each objGroup In objUser.Groups
        CreateMemberOfObject.Add objGroup.Name, "-"
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: What did you try already? Did you have encounter any specific problems we can help with?

Comment: I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're disabling all accounts whose last login was more than 90 days ago, even if the account already is disabled. Add a condition that matches only accounts that are not disabled, and the code will do what you want:

```
If DateDiff("d", dtmLast, Now) > 90 And Not objUser.AccountDisabled Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  Thank you.